# Configure Owin middleware to report status and substatus codes to IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, owin

How does Owin middleware return a status and substatus code, say 403.4, to IIS?

When running an application under IIS, it is often useful not to report a status code, e.g. 403, but to return a substrates too, e.g. 403.4. IIS will log the substatus alongside the status code, which in turn can be analyzed by [SIEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_information_and_event_management) products to detect abnormal traffic.

In the case of IIS, it also allows for custom error messages to be displayed for example 403, 403.1, 403.4 and so forth.

It seems I can only set the status code.

```
public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
    if (!context.Request.IsSecure)
    {
        var response = context.Response;
        response.StatusCode = 403;
        response.ReasonPhrase = "Forbidden";
        return;
    }

    await Next.Invoke(context);
}
```